# Mathematica gives imaginary results for polynomials

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

I was trying to plot a very simple polynomial function:

Plot[x^(2./3.),{x,-0.5,-0.2}]

Mathematica tells me that in this region, the result is always imaginary, but from fundamental math the result should be real. So why the difference?

To make the question clear: I know how to get the correct plot, but I want to understand why mathematica gives us imaginary result. How did mathematica do the calculation inside the kernal?

Thanks!

Comment: Because ([see the docs of `Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html), under Scope) "_the principal root is always used_. You can use `CubeRoot[x^2]` or `Surd[x^2, 3]`.

Comment: Great, that answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a terminological note: $x^\frac23$ is an *algebraic* function, but certainly ***not*** a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[CubeRoot[x]^2, {x, -0.5, -0.2}]
```

or

```
Plot[Surd[x, 3]^2, {x, -0.5, -0.2}]
```

Comment: Hi jiaoeyushushu, thanks for your reply. I actually know how to get the correct plot. But do you know why mathamatica gives us imaginary results? Thanks.

Comment: From the Documentation Center:

Power[x,y] has a branch cut discontinuity for y running from -\[Infinity] to 0 in the complex x plane for noninteger y. Because of this branch cut, Power[x,1/n] returns a complex root by default instead of the real one for negative real x and odd positive n. To obtain a real-valued n\[Null]^th root, Surd[x,n] can be used. The special case CubeRoot[x] corresponds to Surd[x,3].

Comment: @JohnDoty Thank you John and also corey979, your answers solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Guide *Mathematica* to the desired result,

```
Table[(x^(2.))^(1/3.), {x, -0.5, -0.2, 0.1}]
```

> {0.629961, 0.542884, 0.44814, 0.341995}

If you check the internal operation procedure you will see the difference,

```
FullForm[x^(2./3.)]
```

[image]

compare with this

```
FullForm[(x^(2.))^(1/3.)]
```

[image]

You can also try with exact form, i.e., `2/3`.

Comment: Hi zhk, thanks. I know how to get the correct plot, but I want to understand why mathematica gives us imaginary results. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Y.Du Check the edit